# How to print a PDF file stored in MemoryStream or PdfDocument or PdfPage object to a printer?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I am using [Essential Objects](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Default.aspx) to convert an HTML file to PDF, it is working perfectly and I can save the PDF to Hard-drive by using the following method.

```
HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(htmlFileName, outputFileName);
```

In addition to convert it to a file, it can also convert it to any .NET Stream object. For example, you can convert it to a `MemoryStream` object, then retrieve the raw bytes of the PDF file from the MemoryStream and attach it to an email or any other purpose, all without creating any physical file at all by using the following method.

```
HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtml(htmlCode, memoryStream or pdfDocument or pdfPage);
```

Now my problem is that how can I print the PDF file stored in `MemoryStream` or `PdfDocument` or `PdfPage` to a printer?

Answer (score 1):

You can print a PDF document to a printer using the PdfPrinter class from [HiQPdf library](http://www.hiqpdf.com):

```
PdfPrinter pdfPrinter = new HiQPdf.PdfPrinter();
pdfPrinter.PrintPdf(pdfStream);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), its the way to go when printing in c#. To quote from the msdn site

> Typically, you create an instance of the PrintDocument class, set properties such as the DocumentNameand PrinterSettings, and call the Print method to start the printing process. Handle the PrintPage event where you specify the output to print, by using the GraphicsGraphics property of the PrintPageEventArgs.

Comment: I have a pdf file already created in memory so I cannot print it using the Graphics object provided by the PrintDocument! The graphics object is only for drawing graphics and string but not pdf file.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this method wil be helpfull.

```
    public void Print(string printerName, string fileName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            return;

        var url = fileName;
        var filePath = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.pdf", Application.StartupPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            client.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Form1.SelectedPrinter))
            return;

        PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();

        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 140;
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 104;


        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo gsProcessInfo;
            Process gsProcess;

            gsProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            gsProcessInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
            gsProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //The default is false.
            gsProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            gsProcessInfo.FileName = filePath;
            gsProcessInfo.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";
            gsProcess = Process.Start(gsProcessInfo);
            gsProcess.WaitForExit(4000);
            if (gsProcess.HasExited == false)
            {
                gsProcess.Kill();
            }
            gsProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            gsProcess.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```